# SQL Server - Server name same as the instance name and most common use for instances?

Tags: sql-server

Is the server name the same thing as an instance name? I have looked around and am not sure; I think they are but I don't just want to guess.

Also, what is the most common use for SQL instances? I understand why it would be useful to have different instances, but I would like to know what others find the most use of it from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Servers are like the physical location. Instances are the actual SQL Server functionality. They are what you connect to in order to use SQL Server.

- Each Instance belongs to only one Server.
- You can have multiple instances per Server (so T_COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS and T_COMPUTER\SQLSERVER could be 2 instances on the same Server).
- An Instance is a fully self contained SQL Server installation.
- You can have a default instance configured, which is the Instance accessed when you connect to the Server directly (i.e. T_COMPUTER, actually connects to T_COMPUTER\INSTANCE)

Answer (score 2):

They can be the same, but don't have to be.  But you can also have a [named instance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165614%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) that gives a unique name allowing you to have multiple instances on the same server.  In the past I've seen that used in order to have a separate development and production instance but have them both on the same server machine.